# How do I prepare for Developer Training in Denver?

Tags: developer

I am signed up for the developer training in Denver.  What do I need to bring to the training? Is there anything I should study before the training?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to be starting here at the developer wiki - http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Develop

and continuing here - 
http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/GitHub+for+CiviCRM

and I might just buy the book here, though it may be out of date- [http://www.amazon.com/Using-CiviCRM-Joseph-Murray/dp/1849512264](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1849512264)

Answer (score 1):

You need a wifi enabled laptop. Beyond that, I would see what your instructors recommend. @Joe McLaughlin's suggestions for prepping the machine and doing a bit of github stuff for a core commit are good ideas.

While I appreciate the advertising for our book (thanks, Joe!), it was focussed solely on non-developers, so it's not that relevant to the developers course. FWIW, Brian and I are working on a new revision based on 4.6.

Comment: Cool @Joe Murray, I think I reviewed the first chapters :-) Nice to hear you are working on it!

Comment: Thanks Joe, I bought the book anyway, looking forward to the updated version